# Form validation for a dynamic array of questions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem I am facing is, the questions array in the form is a dynamic array that is the questions would be retrieved from the backend and we wouldn't know the actual length of the array. So, I have used a map function to display the questions in the form.

Now I need to validate the input fields such that they do not start with whitespaces. i have written the regex expression for that. But the issue is that the error message is getting displayed for all the fields even though a single input field starts with a whitespace.
Whereas, the correct requirement is that the error message should be displayed only below the field which does not meet my validation criteria.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const pattern = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9]");
```

//This is the handle change code snippet//

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (!pattern.test(e.target.value)) {
      setError("Enter a valid input");
      e.target.value = "";
    }
  };

// This is the map function//
let questionsList = questions.map((data, id) => {
    const Question = `Ques-${id}`;
    return (
      <div key={id} className="form-group fgself">
        <label htmlFor={Question}>
          <b>{data}</b>
          <div className="selfreq">*</div>
        </label>
        <textarea
          type="text"
          className="form-control fcself"
          name={id}
          id={Question}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Enter your response"
          required
        ></textarea>
        {error}
      </div>
    );
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.trim()` method to remove white spaces

Comment: No, I don't have idea about this function.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to check if you have white space in the start of an input, and to check if the input is focused or active, something like this ( i used one function called app.js but it's basically your code just change App to questionsList )

```
function App() {
    const [ error, setError ] = useState('');
    const re = new RegExp('^[ ]');
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        if (re.test(e.target.value)) {
            setError('Enter a valid input');
            e.target.value = '';
        } else {
            setError('');
        }
    };
    return questions.map(({ data, id }) => {
        const Question = `Ques-${id}`;
        return (
            <div key={id} className="form-group fgself">
                <label htmlFor={Question}>
                    <b>{data}</b>
                    <div className="selfreq">*</div>
                </label>
                <textarea
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control fcself"
                    name={id}
                    id={Question}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    placeholder="Enter your response"
                    required
                />
                {error && document.getElementById(Question) === document.activeElement && <span>{error}</span>}
            </div>
        );
    });
}

export default App;
```